# Set value for HTML control attribute marked as run at server

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Asp.Net Web Forms stops rendering value of `<%#: Item %>` for HTML control attribute once control is marked as run at server. Herewith snippet of Repeater ItemTemplate:

```
<a id="RepeaterElement" runat="server" href="?code=<%#: Item %>"><%#: Item %></a>
```

The resulting HTML code instead of `href="?code=MyValue"` becomes literally what it is behind the scenes `href="?code=<%#: Item %>"`.

How can I manipulate with attributes of HTML control marked as run at server from .aspx file within Repeater Item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, but you need the `?code=` in the databinding expression.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" ItemType="System.String">
    <ItemTemplate>

        <a id="RepeaterElement" runat="server" href='<%# "?code=" + Item %>'><%# Item %></a>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. What is the rationale behind, when compared to a non run at server `<a>` control?